# How to change the custom color of the theme "Warsaw"?

Tags: beamer, themes

Does anyone know how to change the *dark blue* in the theme `Warsaw` to other other colors?

I tried :

```
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red!80!black,bg=red!20!white}
```

and

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{fg=red!80!black,bg=red!20!white}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Before attempting to manually change colors, check the beamer documentation and see the selection of color themes available to choose from (the [`beamer matrix`](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) could also be useful); a little example using `spruce`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{spruce}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If none of the existing color themes satisfy you, you can change, for example, the `structure` color (or one of the palettes):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately, the color of blocks and definitions are not affected